# Method 'Offset' of Object 'Range' failed on MAC works on Windows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert rows based on certain conditions while looping through a column. My VBA script work on Windows but not on Mac and gives the following error: Run-time error '1004': Method 'Offset' of object 'Range failed. The first if statement in the code block below is where the code breaks down on Mac:

```
lastRow = Range("C5", Range("C5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
for i = 0 to (lastRow+1)

  'Conditions: check if the current cell is not empty, if the cell has the value, and if var_con# is not true

   If IsEmpty(Range("C5").Offset(i,0)) <> True and Range("C5").Offset(i,0).Value = 10 and var_con1 <> True Then
     Range("C5").Offset(i,0).EntireRow.Insert
     var_con1 = True
     i = i + 1
   ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("C5").Offset(i,0)) <> True and Range("C5").Offset(i,0).Value = 5 and var_con2 <> True
     Range("C5").Offset(i,0).EntireRow.Insert
     var_con2 = True
     i = i + 1
   End If
Next i
```

Using Excel version 16.71 on Mac and Excel 2019 on windows

Comment: What's the value of `i` when it fails?

Comment: I should have debugged this before posting, but the statement ```lastRow = Range("C5", Range("C5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count``` in Mac is getting to set to the last row of the entire excel file. I will try this from your post ```ws.Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp)```

Comment: This is not a Windows vs Mac issue. You should specify the worksheet where this is happening, e.g. `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` because the `lastRow` might have been calculated on the wrong worksheet (another worksheet was active at the time). Then you will have to use this `ws` variable with a dot (`ws.`) in front of each not dotted occurrence of `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns` e.g. `ws.Range(...)`. A relatively safer way to get the last row is to use the `Find` method: `lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row`.

Comment: @ Tim Williams, @ VBasic2008 The last row was getting calculated from a different workbook that was open. After setting it to the required sheet, everything works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking it's not good practice to increment a For counter within the loop.  If you want to do that then you need a different type of loop.

Eg:

```vb
Sub TT()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim var_con1 As Boolean, var_con2 As Boolean, v
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'consider using `ws.Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp)` instead
    lastRow = ws.Range("C5", ws.Range("C5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    
    i = 0
    Do While i < lastRow + 1
        Set c = ws.Range("C5").Offset(i)
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            If v = 10 And Not var_con1 Then
                c.EntireRow.Insert
                i = i + 1
                var_con1 = True
                If var_con2 Then Exit Do 'no more actions to take
            ElseIf v = 5 And Not var_con2 Then
                c.EntireRow.Insert
                i = i + 1
                var_con2 = True
                If var_con1 Then Exit Do 'no more actions to take
            End If
        End If 'any cell value
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```